# RETOPOLOGY: am I doing it correctly? If yes, how time-consuming is it supposed to be for a full model?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[[image: ?[1]]

This is the head of a bird model I'm making. The red is the retopo (plane meshes).

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should add details about the tools you're using for the retopo.